# Flashlog.txt not getting appended

Tags: apache-flex, logging

i have flash debugger version 10. The click on the app is initiated using a test tool and flash logs are collected locally on user machine.

The log file is getting cleared every time the user logs out of the application.

Tried PolicyFileLogAppend=1 line in mm.cfg file at the user terminal.
But no luck. The log file gets clearned when the user logs out of the app.

My test is like login1>do task1> logout1 > login2 > do task 2 > logout2
When login2 gets executed the file gets cleared. finally it holds the log of the task2 alone. 
Any input?

Answer (score 0):

The `PolicyFileLogAppend` setting just affects the [policy file log](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7ec4.html), not flashlog.txt.  I don't believe there is any setting that does the same thing for the flashlog.  There is a big list of settings for mm.cfg [here](http://jpauclair.net/2010/02/10/mmcfg-treasure/), and it doesn't have anything for appending to the flash log.

Searching revealed someone else who had the same issue as you; they wrote a separate tool to maintain an archive of flashlog.txt before it got overwritten.  You might be able to do something similar.  More details [here](http://backroom.bostonproductions.com/?tag=flashlog-txt).